# pattern matching of the form: Option{..} <-

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

What is this form of pattern matching called:`Option{..} <- ...`, e.g. as it is used here:

```
data Option = Option { cabal :: Maybe String , noStylish :: Bool }
...
main = do
  Option{..} <- cmdArgs defOption
  cabp <- case cabal of
    Nothing -> do
    ...
```

It seems to redefine `cabal` and `nostylish`. Before the pattern match `cabal` has type `Option -> Maybe String` but after it has type `Maybe String`.

This example comes from the recently uploaded package `cabal2ghci`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a GHC syntactic extension called [record wildcards](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-wildcards). Quoting documentation:

> Record wildcard syntax permits a `".."` in a record pattern, where each elided field `f` is replaced by the pattern `f = f`.

So this code is equivalent to

```
Option { cabal = cabal, noStylish = noStylish } <- cmdArgs defOption
```

effectively binding name `x` to the value of record field named `x` for every field in the record type.

`<-` part is irrelevant here, you can as well write

```
let Option { .. } = some expression
```